# how to make chart using data from database?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, charts

HI 
i am making a window application using visual studio 2010 and vb.net. i want to make charts daynimacilly using data from the database. how this can be done?

thanks 
Yatin

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has a set of [charting controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c) that you can download for free.  There are extensive sample applications in both c# and vb.net for ASP.Net and Windows Forms that come packaged with the controls.  You should be able to find what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The following could be usefull:

[Samples Environment for .NET Framework 4 Chart Controls Released!](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart)

Answer (score 0):

There is a chart control installed out of the box in Visual Studio 2010 - Have a look in your control toolbox under Data. To start you off, have a look at the [System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.aspx)